# Meteor mongo collection touch

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

I would like to know if I can do such operation as 'touch' for mongo documents in Meteor.

I am using `aldeed:collection2` package to validate the database schema. Having recently added some new fields with default values, I now need to perform migration on my database.

Rather than writing separate migrations for each new fields, my plan is to *touch* all the documents so that the defaultValue defined using `aldeed:simple-schema` are applied to the documents.

Is there a touch operation? How can I proceed?

Comment: MongoDB itself is "schemaless", so all your definitions apply to your "client" code and not the server. Thus the only way to "apply default fields" is to either 1. Read everything one at a time, create object instace, save object instance with changes. 2. Realize this is non performant and write your migration code manually with optimized operations. Nothing in your question to provide a guide to what these changes actually are. Some changes may be simple operations, and some may require some bulk iteration.

Comment: @BlakesSeven That makes sense. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate over each document in your collection, `validate`, and update. That's effectively "touch"-ing each document. Performance shouldn't be a concern for you as this is a one-time migration. The steps are:

1. Validate the doc with SimpleSchema `validate(doc)` which automatically applies `defaultValue`s to the doc object
2. `collection.update(doc)`

Here's an example implementation.

```
collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  MySchema.namedContext("myContext").validate(doc);
  collection.update({_id: doc._id}, doc);
});
```

That should do it!

---

**Note:**
To take advantage of SimpleSchema, you'll obviously have to run this code from a Meteor context (not mongo) which can be tricky to do in a production environment. So, you could write this migration as a server-side method that you call from the client (be sure to secure it) or from Meteor shell if, based on your implementation, you have that available.